# How to deal with python parsing a page with ajax

Tags: python, html, ajax

I have a problem that hard to explain for me cause I'm not sure my guess is right.
I'm trying to parse some data from website using `requests` python's module.

So, I did visit page, pressed Inspect Element on data I want to parse and Chrome highlighted line for me `<span class="pages-count">20</span>`. So `20` is what I want.
I wrote this code for it.

```
def get_pages(html):
    pointer = '<span class="pages-count">'
    start = html.index(pointer) + len(pointer)
    end = html.index('</span>', start)
    return html[start:end]

page = requests.get(url)

print(get_pages(page.text))
```

Nothing was printed. Then I modified code to watch whole line and I realized that I got `<span class="pages-count"></span>`.
Then I checked source code via Ctrl+U and saw same result.
Since I'm bad at web programming - my only guess is that some ajax script put this data after loading page.
So - am I right? And if yes - is there any chance to parse that data?

Comment: You could try a browser automation tool such as `selenium`

Comment: One thing I'd suggest you is to use package like this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html You can use requests to fetch content and than pass it to HTMLParser.feed